# Really confused about the chord algorithm

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems

I'm looking at the pseudocode for chord algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(peer-to-peer)):

```
// create a new Chord ring.
n.create()
    predecessor := nil
    successor := n

// join a Chord ring containing node n'.
n.join(n')
    predecessor := nil
    successor := n'.find_successor(n)

// called periodically. n asks the successor
// about its predecessor, verifies if n's immediate
// successor is consistent, and tells the successor about n
n.stabilize()
    x = successor.predecessor
    if x ∈ (n, successor) then
        successor := x
    successor.notify(n)

// n' thinks it might be our predecessor.
n.notify(n')
    if predecessor is nil or n'∈(predecessor, n) then
        predecessor := n'

// called periodically. refreshes finger table entries.
// next stores the index of the finger to fix
n.fix_fingers()
    next := next + 1
    if next > m then
        next := 1
    finger[next] := find_successor(n+{\displaystyle 2^{next-1}}2^{next-1});

// called periodically. checks whether predecessor has failed.
n.check_predecessor()
    if predecessor has failed then
        predecessor := nil
```

I'm struggling to make sense of it. My question specifically is: when exactly will the `predecessor` field EVER be non-null?

Consider a case where a node id 1 joins. Its successor is 1, the predecessor is nil.

Now say node with 10 joins. Its successor is 1, predecessor is nil.

The stabilization routine depends on the predecessor being non-nil, which in this case it isn't both nodes.

So how does the algorithm proceed at this point?